# Class does not exist. Определение class в Yii2 RBAC rules

Tags: yii2, rules

Здравствуйте. Пишу первый раз на форуме с проблемой. При попытке создать Rule нужно указать имя и класс. Но выдает ошибку:

> Class "_" does not exist.

Где задавать классы для RBAC?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за extension хоть?

Comment: @Blacknife извини, не понял тебя. Только начинаю изучать. В какой директории находится extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все. Можно закрывать. Уже разобрался. ) 
В классе нужно было прописывать путь. 
К примеру, как было у меня:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]